# Java Brickbreaker Block Collision Not Functioning Properly

Tags: java

I'm currently coding a simple game of brickbreaker, however I've come across a huge roadblock. The collisions I have declared are going off on the wrong bricks sometimes, also there is a lot of internal bouncing of the ball. On top of that the loop that draws the non hit blocks goes out of bounds but no matter how much I've tried tinkering with it I have not been able to fix it. Any help would be extremely appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```js
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class brickBreakerApplet extends Applet implements Runnable, KeyListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
{
 private int speed;
 
 int currentLine;
 int x_pos = 30;   
 int y_pos = 100;  
 int x_speed = 1;
 int y_speed = 1;
 int radius = 5;  
 int appletsize_x = 400; 
 int appletsize_y = 300; 
 int mousex=0;
 int mousey=0;
 int score=0;
 int life=3;
 int counter=0;
 int[] bricks;
 Boolean game=false;
 Image background;
 

 private Image dbImage;
 private Graphics dbg;

 public void init()
 {
  setBackground (Color.blue);
  background = getImage(getCodeBase(), "background.gif");
  
  bricks=new int[50];
  
  for (int x=0; x<50; x++){
    bricks[x]=1;
  }
  
  currentLine = 10;
  
  addKeyListener(this);
  addMouseListener(this);
  addMouseMotionListener(this);
 }

 public void start ()
 {
  Thread th = new Thread (this);
  th.start ();
 }

 public void stop()
 {

 }
 
 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
 {
   if (e.getKeyChar() == 'r'){
     x_pos=0;
     y_pos=0;
     x_speed=1;
     y_speed=1;
   }
  currentLine+=20;
 }

 public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
 {
//  System.out.println("User released key " + e.getKeyChar());
//  currentLine+=20;
 }

 public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
 {

 }

 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
 {
//  System.out.println("User clicked mouse " + e.getClickCount() + " times!");
//  currentLine+=20;
 }

 public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
 {
//  System.out.println("Mouse entered applet at " + e.getX() + " " + e.getY());
//  currentLine += 20;
 }

 public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
 {

 }

 public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
 {
   if (game==false){
     x_speed=1;
     y_speed=-1;
     game=true;
   }
   if (life==0){
     x_pos=0;
     y_pos=0;
     x_speed=1;
     y_speed=1;
     life=3;
     score=0;
     game=false;
   }
 }

 public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
 {

 }

 public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
 {
   mousex=e.getX();
   mousey=e.getY();
 }

 public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
 {
 }


 public void destroy()
 {

 }

 public void run ()
 {
  Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);

  while (true)
  {

    
   if (x_pos > appletsize_x - radius)
   {
     if (x_speed==1){
       x_speed = -1;
     }
     if (x_speed==2){
       x_speed = -2;
     }
   }
   else if (x_pos < radius)
   {
     if (x_speed==-1){
       x_speed = +1;
     }
     if (x_speed==-2){
       x_speed= 2;
     }
   }
   else if (y_pos < radius)
   {
     y_speed = +1;
   }
   else if (y_pos > appletsize_y - radius)
   {
     death();
   }
   if (game==true){
     
     
     x_pos += x_speed;
     y_pos += y_speed;
     
    //HITTING TWICE, LOTS OF ERRORS WHILE RUNNING CODE, ASK SIR FOR ASSISTANCE TOMORROW. LOOKS PRETTY GOOD THOUGH.
     
     counter=0;
     for (int y=0; y<5; y++){
       for (int x=0; x<10; x++){
         if (y_pos-(radius)==(40+y*10) &&((x_pos+(radius)>=(x*40) && (x_pos+radius<= 40+(x*40)))) && bricks[counter]==1 && y_speed==-1){
           bricks[counter]=0;
           score++;
           y_speed=1;
         }
         counter++;
       }
     }
     
     counter=0;
     for (int y=0; y<5; y++){
       for (int x=0; x<10; x++){
         if (y_pos+(radius)==(30+y*10) && ((x_pos+(radius)>=(x*40) && (x_pos+radius<= 40+(x*40)))) && bricks[counter]==1 && y_speed==1){
           bricks[counter]=0;
           score++;
           y_speed=-1;
         }
         counter++;
       }
     }
     
     counter=0;
     for (int y=0; y<5; y++){
       for (int x=0; x<10; x++){
         if (x_pos+radius==(x*40) && ((y_pos>=(30+(y*10)) && (y_pos<= 40+(y*10)))) && bricks[counter]==1){
           bricks[counter]=0;
           score++;
           x_speed=-1;
         }
         counter++;
       }
     }
     
     counter=0;
     for (int y=0; y<5; y++){
       for (int x=0; x<10; x++){
         if (x_pos-radius==(40+(x*40)) && ((y_pos>=(30+(y*10)) && (y_pos<= 40+(y*10)))) && bricks[counter]==1){
           bricks[counter]=0;
           score++;
           x_speed=1;
         }
         counter++;
       }
     }     
   
     if (y_pos >= 280-(radius))
     {
       {
         if ((x_pos+(radius) >= mousex-30) && (x_pos+(radius) <= mousex-20)){
           score++;
           difficulty();
           x_speed=-2;
           java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
           
         }
         if ((x_pos+(radius) >= mousex-20) && (x_pos+(radius) <= mousex)){
           score++;
           difficulty();
           x_speed=-1;
           java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
           
         }
         if ((x_pos+(radius) >= mousex) && (x_pos+(radius) <= mousex+20)){
           score++;
           difficulty();
           x_speed=1;
           java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
           
         }
         if ((x_pos+(radius) >= mousex+20) && (x_pos+(radius) <= mousex+30)){
           score++;
           difficulty();
           x_speed=2;
           java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
           
         }
         
       }
     }
   }
   
   if (game==false){
     x_pos=mousex;
     y_pos= 279-radius;
   }
   

   

   repaint();
  

   try
   {
    Thread.sleep (5);
   }
   catch (InterruptedException ex)
   {
    // do nothing
   }
   Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
  }
 }
 
 public void update (Graphics g)
 {
  if (dbImage == null)
  {
   dbImage = createImage (this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);
   dbg = dbImage.getGraphics ();
  }

  dbg.setColor (getBackground ());
  dbg.fillRect (0, 0, this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);

  dbg.setColor (getForeground());
  paint (dbg);
  
  g.drawImage (dbImage, 0, 0, this);
 }

 public void paint (Graphics g)
 {
   if (life>0){
     
     g.drawImage(background,0,0,this);
     
     g.setColor  (Color.cyan);
     
     g.fillOval (x_pos - radius, y_pos - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
     
     g.setColor (Color.blue);
     
     g.fillRect (mousex-30, 280, 60, 5);
     
     g.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 20));
     
     g.setColor (Color.cyan);
     
     g.drawString ("Score: "+score, 5,20);
     
     g.drawString ("Life: "+life, 330,20);
     
     counter=0;
     for (int y=0; y<5; y++){
       for (int x=0; x<10; x++){
         if (bricks[counter]==1){
           g.setColor(Color.blue);
           g.fillRect(x*40, 30+(y*10),40,10);
           g.setColor(Color.black);
           g.drawRect(x*40, 30+(y*10),40,10);
         }
         counter++;
       }
     }
   }
   
   if (life==0){
     g.setColor (Color.black);
     g.fillRect (0,0,400,400);
     g.setColor (Color.white);
     g.setFont (new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 48));
     g.drawString ("GAME OVER", 50, 150);
     g.setFont (new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 12));
     g.drawString ("To Try Again, Press Screen", 130, 160);
     g.drawString ("Your Score Was: "+score, 155, 170);
   }
 }
 
 public void death ()
 {
   game=false;
   y_pos= 279-radius;
   life--;
   
 }
 
 public void difficulty()
 {
   y_speed=-1;
 }
 }
```

Comment: In 300 lines of code posted, you should provide us some more precise information on where this collision detection happens. Your `run` method is extremely large, break it down to smaller methods to help you (and us) debug your problem

Comment: Applet???????? Really?